# How to set a default value primefaces dropdown?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

can anyone please tell me how to set a default value to the primefaces dropdown. the defauklt value will be coming from the datatable..

```
<h:outputLabel for="leaveType" value="Type of Leave *:" styleClass="tLabel"/>
<p:selectOneMenu id="leaveType" value="#{leaveBean.selectedLeave.leaveType}" disabled="#{leaveBean.selectedLeave.status!='Pending'}" >
<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{leaveBean.selectedLeave.leaveType}" itemValue="" />
<f:selectItems value="#{leaveBean.leaveDTO.infoBeanList}" var="lType" itemValue="#{lType.leaveTypeCode}@#{lType.leaveType}" itemLabel="#{lType.leaveType}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Where is the code you're working with?

Comment: Just initialize `leaveBean.selectedLeave.leaveType` to a value in the managed bean, preferably in a `@PostConstruct` method

Comment: There is a datatable ..once user selects a row from the datatable then the value of the dropdown need to be populated based on the value from the datatbale and also the dropdown initially contains some values

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one.

```
public static SelectItem[] getSelectItems(List<?> entities, boolean selectOne) {
    int size = selectOne ? entities.size() + 1 : entities.size();
    SelectItem[] items = new SelectItem[size];
   int i =0;
    for (Object x : entities) {
      items[i++] = new SelectItem(x, x.toString());
    }
    return items;
  }
```

`List<?> entities` will be the list result.

and then make sure you have the code below in your entity class.

```
@Override
  public String toString() {
    return this.name;
  }
```